# Creating datetime range from unique dates and list of time range

Tags: python, datetime

I have two list
1st of unique dates and second of time
I want to create datetime range

eg.

```
Date = [datetime.date(2020, 12, 28) datetime.date(2020, 12, 29)
 datetime.date(2020, 12, 30) datetime.date(2020, 12, 31)]

Time  = [datetime.time(9, 15) datetime.time(10, 30) datetime.time(11, 45)
 datetime.time(13, 0) datetime.time(14, 15)]
```

Want output

| Datetime |
| --- |
| 2020-12-28 09:15:00 |
| 2020-12-28 10:30:00 |
| 2020-12-28 11:45:00 |
| 2020-12-28 13:00:00 |
| 2020-12-28 14:15:00 |
| 2020-12-29 09:15:00 |
| 2020-12-29 10:30:00 |
| 2020-12-29 11:45:00 |
| 2020-12-29 13:00:00 |
| 2020-12-29 14:15:00 |

and so on

Thanks and regards

Comment: Did you try anything? There is [datetime.combine](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine) for example

Comment: Searched but couldn't find proper solution and hence posted on the stack. Thanks for reply and edit

Comment: if you need a list of datetime objects, you can simply use `[datetime.combine(d, t) for d in Date for t in Time]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *nested list comprehension* to achieve this:

```
import datetime

date = [datetime.date(2020, 12, 28), datetime.date(2020, 12, 29), datetime.date(2020, 12, 30), datetime.date(2020, 12, 31)]
time = [datetime.time(9, 15), datetime.time(10, 30), datetime.time(11, 45), datetime.time(13, 0), datetime.time(14, 15)]

output_list = ["{} {}".format(d, t) for d in date for t in time]
```

where `output_list` contains:

```
[
'2020-12-28 09:15:00', 
'2020-12-28 10:30:00', 
'2020-12-28 11:45:00', 
'2020-12-28 13:00:00', 
'2020-12-28 14:15:00', 
'2020-12-29 09:15:00', 
'2020-12-29 10:30:00', 
'2020-12-29 11:45:00', 
'2020-12-29 13:00:00', 
'2020-12-29 14:15:00', 
'2020-12-30 09:15:00', 
'2020-12-30 10:30:00', 
'2020-12-30 11:45:00', 
'2020-12-30 13:00:00', 
'2020-12-30 14:15:00', 
'2020-12-31 09:15:00', 
'2020-12-31 10:30:00', 
'2020-12-31 11:45:00', 
'2020-12-31 13:00:00', 
'2020-12-31 14:15:00'
]
```